# Iterating through iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

iterrows can be used to iterate through a pandas dataframe:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

How can I use a second for loop to iterate through each element in the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterrows returns a tuple. The element indexed by [1] contains the row. You can then iterate through that element.

```
for row in x.iterrows():
    print(row[1])
    for b in row[1]:
        print(b)
```