# Box Plot Pandas of a vector within columns fields

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have a DataFrame in pandas like this:

```
                 rank                                 array_for_box_plot  \
 sequence                                                                
    1         1.111111       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, ...   

    2         0.714286         [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1]   
    3         0.900000                     [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]   
    4         1.300000                     [3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]   
    5         0.111111                        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   
    6         0.444444                        [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I would plot a boxplot where in x axis I should have the relative 'sequence' and the boxplot for the column 'array_for_box_plot' for each 'array'

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['frequency', 'array_for_box_plot'], data=data)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
boxplot = ax.boxplot(df.array_for_box_plot.values.tolist())
```

Which yields:
[image]

Data Used:

```
data = [
    [1, [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2]],
    [2, [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1]],
    [3, [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],
    [4, [3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]],
    [5, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    [6, [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]],
]
```

Comment: No, because I just have my data within a Data Frame in the order explained above. Do you know if there is a function or call to bloxplot arrays within a datagrame in pandas?

Comment: seriously @user7311536 he solved your problem exactly. are you even paying attention to the code?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Great absolutely. Great to @Jan

Answer (score 0):

If you're wedded to that data structure, then you'll need to iterate through each row and build your plot: [Example of row iteration.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801796/37751)

But that's not very pandas-esque. A more pandas style solution would be to repeat the `rank` for every observation in the boxplot data then group by `rank`